# swift iOS - Can't reset gameScene when character is off screen

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, skphysicsbody

I've recently put the finishing touches to my first app however I've spotted a bug that is driving me crazy!

The object of the game is the character (a cat), jumps over obstacles but also has to avoid birds that fly through the air, the score increases every time a bird fly past without contact.

The game is over if contact is made when the cat makes contact with a bird or if the cat fails to jump over an obstacle and is pushed back to the left edge of the screen where a dummy contact node is placed.

Now the bug... everything works as expected however if the cat is in mid air when a bird makes contact the collision propels the cat off the visible screen, at this stage the player is then unable to reset the scene by tapping the screen, only if the cat is visible on the screen would you be able to reset the scene by tapping once and play again.

Here is all the code I could think of that may be useful, if anyone knows how this bug can be crushed please let me know.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

//details of the cat

    cat = SKSpriteNode(texture: catTexture1)
    cat.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.2, y: self.frame.size.height / 5.1 )
    cat.runAction(run, withKey: "runningAction")
    cat.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: cat.size.height / 2.0)
    cat.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    cat.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    cat.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = catCategory
    cat.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = crowCategory | worldCategory
    cat.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = crowCategory | contact2Category
    cat.physicsBody!.restitution = -10

    moving.addChild(cat)

//contact node increases score when bird makes contact

    var contact = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(1, 450))
    contact.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 3.3, y: self.frame.size.height / 2.0 )
    contact.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(1, 450))
    contact.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    contact.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    contact.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = scoreCategory
    contact.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = crowCategory

    self.addChild(contact)

//2nd contact node runs game over code

    var contact2 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(1, 450))
    contact2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 4.0, y: self.frame.size.height / 2.0 )
    contact2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(1, 450))
    contact2.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    contact2.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    contact2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = contact2Category
    contact2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = catCategory

    self.addChild(contact2)

//touch that initiates reset

override func  touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if ableToJump == true {
    if (moving.speed > 0){

        cat.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        cat.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 30))

                } else if (canRestart) {
        resetLabelNode.hidden = true
        self.resetScene()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think  when you character is off screen it's parameters are no processed and moving.speed is equal to 0. Thats why condition if (moving.speed > 0) is not satisfied

Comment: @alex_p that's interesting, would you know how I could set parameters to the cat so it would be unable to go off screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer to this on a similar post, what they recommended was to set a frame round the visible screen.  I just added the below code to `didMoveToView`

```
    let frame = CGRectMake(255, 0, 515, self.frame.size.height)
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: frame)
```

I hope this helps someone in the future!